# Listen only to additions to a cloud firestore collection in python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Code should only trigger if new documents are ADDED to a specific collection in firebase.

I have already found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965147/listen-only-to-additions-to-a-cloud-firestore-collection) for this problem in javascript, but I can't figure out the solution for python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) contains an example of how to do that (look at the "python" tab):

> ```
> def on_snapshot(col_snapshot, changes, read_time):
>     print(u'Callback received query snapshot.')
>     print(u'Current cities in California: ')
>     for change in changes:
>         if change.type.name == 'ADDED':
>             print(u'New city: {}'.format(change.document.id))
>         # Removed other cases
>
> col_query = db.collection(u'cities').where(u'state', u'==', u'CA')
>
> # Watch the collection query
> query_watch = col_query.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
> ```