# Duplicate lists printing after adding new document to firestore collection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

When the component loads, it pulls all the data from a specific collection in firestore and renders it just fine. then when i add a new document, it adds that document but then prints them all out (including the new one) under the previous list.

This is my first real react project and I am kinda clueless. I have tried resetting the state when the component loads and calling the method at different times.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// Database Ref
import Firebase from '../../Config/Firebase';

// Stylesheet
import '../View-Styles/views.scss';

// Componenents
import Post from '../../Components/Post/Post';
import EntryForm from '../../Components/EntryForm/EntryForm';

export class Gym extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.collection = 'Gym';

        this.app = Firebase;
        this.db = this.app.firestore().collection('Gym');

        this.state = {
            posts: []
        };

        this.addNote = this.addNote.bind(this);
    };


    componentDidMount() {

        this.currentPosts = this.state.posts;

        this.db.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                this.currentPosts.push({
                    id: doc.id,
                    // title: doc.data().title,
                    body: doc.data().body
                });
            });

            this.setState({
                posts: this.currentPosts
            });
        });
    };

    addNote(post) {
        // console.log('post content:', post );
        this.db.add({
            body: post
        })
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div className="view-body">
                <div>
                    {
                        this.state.posts.map((post) => {
                            return(
                                <div className="post">
                                    <Post key={post.id} postId={post.id} postTitle={post.title} postBody={post.body} />
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
                <div className="entry-form">
                    <EntryForm addNote={this.addNote} collection={this.collection} />
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    };
};

export default Gym;
```

I am trying to get it to only add the new document to the list, rather than rendering another complete list with the new document. no error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies with your `componentDidMount()` function and the use of `onSnapshot()`. Each time an update to your collection occurs, any listeners attached with `onSnapshot()` will be triggered. In your listener, you add each document in the snapshot to the existing list. While this list starts off empty, on every subsequent change, the list is appended to with all of the documents in the collection (including the old ones, not just the changes).

There are two ways to handle the listener's snapshot when it comes in - either empty the existing list and recreate it on each change, or only handle the changes (new entries, deleted entries, etc).

As a side note: When using `onSnapshot()`, it is recommended to store the "unsubscribe" function that it returns (e.g. `this.stopChangeListener = this.db.onSnapshot(...)`). This allows you later to freeze the state of your list without receiving further updates from the server by calling `someGym.stopChangeListener()`.

#### Recreate method

*For simplicity, I'd recommend using this method unless you are dealing with a large number of items.*

```
componentDidMount() {

    this.stopChangeListener = this.db.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        var postsArray = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
            return {
                id: doc.id,
                // title: doc.data().title,
                body: doc.data().body
            });
        });

        this.currentPosts = postsArray;
        this.setState({
            posts: postsArray
        });
    });
};
```

#### Replicate changes method

*This method is subject to race-conditions and opens up the possibility of desyncing with the database if handled incorrectly.*

```
componentDidMount() {

    this.stopChangeListener = this.db.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        var postsArray = this.currentPosts.clone() // take a copy to work with.

        snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
            var doc = change.document;
            var data = {
                id: doc.id,
                // title: doc.data().title,
                body: doc.data().body
            });
            switch(change.type) {
              case 'added':
                // add new entry
                postsArray.push(data)
                break;
              case 'removed':
                // delete potential existing entry
                var pos = postsArray.findIndex(entry => entry.id == data.id);
                if (pos != -1) {
                  postsArray.splice(pos, 1)
                }
                break;
              case 'modified':
                // update potential existing entry
                var pos = postsArray.findIndex(entry => entry.id == data.id);
                if (pos != -1) {
                  postsArray.splice(pos, 1, data)
                } else {
                  postsArray.push(data)
                }
            }
        });

        this.currentPosts = postsArray; // commit the changes to the copy
        this.setState({
            posts: postsArray
        });
    });
};
```

---

As a side note: I would also consider moving `this.currentPosts = ...` into the `this.setState()` function.

Answer (score 0):

When you use onSnapshot() in Cloud Firestore,you can print only the [added](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) data. For your code, it should be something like:

```
       snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
           if (change.type === "added") {
               console.log("Newly added data: ", change.doc.data());
           }
```

Also, Firestore does not load the entire collection everytime a new data is added, the documents are cached and will be reused when the collection changes again.

For more info, you can checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965147/listen-only-to-additions-to-a-cloud-firestore-collection).