# adding document change type conditions/filter to Firestore snapshot listener

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

Wondering if it's possible to add a snapshot listener that only returns added documents, ignoring modified or removed ones?

I'm using Firestone to pass messages/documents between iOS app instances and after the document is received by the recipient, it deletes the document on the server.  Instead of paying for two reads, one when the document is added and another for when it is deleted, I'd like to just have the snapshot listener fire only for added documents and ignore deletions entirely.

Right now after the snapshot listener returns I'm just checking that the change type equals .added and ignoring .removed.

Thank you!

Colin

code snippet of existing:

```
 firestoreListener = FirebaseManager.shared.firestore
            .collection("user_messages")
            .document(myId)
            .collection("my_messages")
            .order(by: "timestamp")
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                self.errorMessage = "listener failed: \(error)"
                return
            }
        
            querySnapshot?.documentChanges.forEach({ change in
                if change.type == .added {
```

Answer (score 0):

> Wondering if it's possible to add a snapshot listener that only returns added documents, ignoring modified or removed ones?

It's not possible strictly as stated - there is no provided API for that.

If the timestamp field on your documents represents the time the document was added to the collection, what you can do instead is use that to filter only the documents added since a certain time, which you must know on the client.

If you don't want to guess a time, you can first query for only the last document based on timestamp, then use its timestamp to establish a > range for your query.

Your query snapshot will accumulate documents that were added since that time.  You will have to write code to figure out which of that set has been added, and which were there from previous snapshots.

See also:

- [Listen only to additions to a cloud firestore collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965147/listen-only-to-additions-to-a-cloud-firestore-collection)

Comment: Thanks so much Doug, that's a great idea!